# No todos mis commits suben a github

Tags: git, github

Soy  nuevo en el uso de git y estoy intentado subirlo a un repositorio en Github mi problema es que por alguna razón no se suben todos los commits.

El proyecto lo inicie hace algunas semanas así que ya tengo varios commits en mi repo local 6 para ser exactos. Cree un repo en github e hice lo que me indica para asocialos con git remote add  y  git push origin master  para  subir los cambios. Pero cunado reviso el repo en github  solo tengo 2  commits no tengo  idea  de por que sucede  esto, al  hacer el push no me marca error en lo absoluto ni manda algun mensaje de advertencia.

Alguna sugerencia ?  de Ante mano muchas gracias.

[image: git log de mi repo local]

[image: git push al repo remoto]

[image: commits en github]

Comment: No, la terminal dice que todo esta actualizado

Comment: Tiene pinta de que has hecho esos commit sobre una rama "detached" (sin nombre). Por defecto sólo se suben a github los de la rama master. Prueba a hacer `git branch prueba` (para darle un nombre a esa rama anónima que yo sospecho), `git checkout master` (para cambiarte a la master) y `git merge prueba` (para añadir a master los commits de la rama prueba). Tras eso el `push` ya enviaría todos los commits, si mi hipótesis era correcta.

Comment: @abulafia Tiene toda la pinta, porque uno de los commits que tiene en github ni siquiera está presente en el log mostrado, debe estar en otra rama

Comment: @PabloLozano Sí, y que el prompt termine con `(138f8df...)`, que es el hash del último commit de la historia, es lo que me hace sospechar de un _detached HEAD_.

Comment: @abulafia Tenias razón sucede o al menos eso es lo que entiendo en uno de los commits hubo un error y git me movió a otra rama hasta que resolviera el error gracias por la ayuda